# c++ socket programming : sendto() and recvfrom() error code 10038 & in 'server' bind failed with 10038

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

```
//UDP receiver
int main()
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    SOCKET receivingSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN receiverAddr;
    SOCKADDR_IN senderAddr;
    int senderAddrSize = sizeof(senderAddr);
    int port=51020;
    char receiveBuf[1024];
    int bufLength=1024;

    cout << "UDP receiver\n";

    //Initialize winsock
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Failed. Error Code : " << WSAGetLastError();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cout << "Initialised\n";`

    if(receivingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 ) == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        cout << "Could not create socket :" << WSAGetLastError();
    }
    cout << "Socket created.\n";

    //fill up SOCKADDR_IN structure
    senderAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    senderAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    senderAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //Bind information with socket
    bind(receivingSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&senderAddr, sizeof(senderAddr));

    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Waiting for message\n";

        //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
        if (recvfrom(receivingSocket, receiveBuf, 1024, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&senderAddr, &senderAddrSize)) == SOCKET_ERROR))
        {
            cout << "recvfrom() failed with error code :" << WSAGetLastError();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        cout << receiveBuf;
    }

    //Close socket
    closesocket(receivingSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

```
//UDP server
int main()
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    SOCKET sendingSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN receiverAddr;
    int port = 51010;
    char sendBuf[1024]="Hello!!!";
    int bufLength = 1024;

    cout << "UDP server from book\n";

    //Initialize socket
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Failed. Error Code : " << WSAGetLastError();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cout << "Initialised\n";

    if(sendingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Could not create socket : " << WSAGetLastError();
    }
    cout << "Socket created.\n";

    //FIll out structure of receiverAdd
    receiverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    receiverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    receiverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.100");

    int test = bind(sendingSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&receiverAddr, sizeof(receiverAddr));
    if( test < 0)
    {
        cout << "Bind failed with error code : %d" << WSAGetLastError();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cout << "Bind is successful\n";

    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Sending data...\n";

        //Send datagram to receiver
        if(sendto(sendingSocket, sendBuf, 1024, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&receiverAddr, sizeof(receiverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "sendto() failed with error code : " << WSAGetLastError();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        cout << "Sent";
    }

    //close socket
    closesocket(sendingSocket);

    WSACleanup();

    std::cin.get();

   // return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: This code was HORRIBLY formatted. I fixed it for you, but next time please [learn how to properly format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code snippets when posting them.

Comment: You also forgot to look up Winsock error 10038.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 10038 is `WSAENOTSOCK: The descriptor is not a socket.`

You are calling `socket()` and assigning your `SOCKET` handles inside of `if` statements, but you are missing adequate parenthesis.  They should be like this instead:

```
if( (receivingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET )
```

```
if( (sendingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET )
```

Personally, I hate code that performs assignments inside of `if` statements like this.  I prefer to keep them separate.  It is cleaner, less error-prone, and no less efficient from the compiler's perspective:

```
receivingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if( receivingSocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
```

```
sendingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if( sendingSocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
```

On a side note:

1. `WSAStartup()` does not use `WSAGetLastError()` for error reporting, it directly returns an error code instead.  This is clearly stated in the `WSAStartup()` documentation.

   ```
   int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);
   if (err != 0)
   {
       cout << "Failed. Error Code : " << err;
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   ```
2. your UDP receiver is not checking the return value of `bind()` for an error before entering the `recvfrom()` loop.

Comment: Also, debugging is much easier when expressions, conditionals etc. are spread over several lines with intermediate vars, (and optimization off).  Lumping complex expressions into one line means that bugs can be missed, or misinterpreted, while single-stepping through the source.

Comment: 10047 is `WSAEAFNOSUPPORT`. The only way you can get that error with `bind()` is if you did not initialize the `sin_family` correctly. That has nothing to do with the IP that you choose to bind to. When receiving packets, you can bind to `INADDR_ANY`, but when sending packets, you cannot bind to `INADDR_ANY`. An outbound packet must have a specific IP that it is sent from.

Comment: The `sockaddr` you pass to `bind()` represents the *LOCAL* address that `recvfrom()` listens on and `sendto()` sends from. The `sockaddr` you pass to `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` represents the *REMOTE* address, the address being sent to for `sendto()` and the address being sent from for `recvfrom()`. Your naming convention is a little backwards when calling `bind()`, and you should use separate `sockaddr` variables for binding and sending/receiving.

Comment: @Remy. I asked a question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26192877/3042916) but now in well formatted eventhough why question is getting -ve points ?? Please suggest so that i can improve

Comment: @user3042916: that question has nothing to do with this question. Do not hijack questions, it's rude.